# centos folder permission ftp user and apache

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, ftp

I have some folder, need anybodies php scripts can create sub folder/files and unlink files.

I do sudo `chown -R apache:apache /var/www/public_html/a`

But after that, my ftp user cannot upload files in that folder.

And I do `sudo chown -R yulichika:users /var/www/public_html/a`

that ftp can access the folder, but anybodies php scripts with a wrong permisson.

I do not want set the whole folder with 0777, so how to chown 2 users with the permission to operate the same folder? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use access control lists commands.

First set owner apache to the directory

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/public_html/a
```

Now set acl so that ftp user can upload folders.

FOR USER

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:yulichika:rwx /var/www/public_html/a
```

FOR GROUP

```
sudo setfacl -R -m g:users:rwx /var/www/public_html/a
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, fiexed it. `yum install acl`, then do the  code you given